# Change all dates in the entire database with a script by subtracting two hours

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a script to edit all existing dates in the database by subtracting two hours.

**What I tried:**
manually I can do that:

```
USE [MyDatabase]
GO

UPDATE [dbo].[AtableOfMany]
   SET [dateStart] = DATEADD(HOUR,-2, [dateStart])
      ,[dateEnd] = DATEADD(HOUR,-2, [dateEnd])
 WHERE 1=1
GO
```

..but I need to do that for all tables and columns that comes out from the output of the sys.columns:

```
USE [MyDatabase]

select schema_name(t.schema_id) + '.' + t.name as [table]
      ,c.column_id
      ,c.name as column_name
      ,type_name(user_type_id) as data_type
      ,scale as second_scale
from sys.columns c
join sys.tables t on t.object_id = c.object_id

--where type_name(user_type_id) in ('date', 'datetimeoffset', 'datetime2', 'smalldatetime', 'datetime', 'time')
where type_name(user_type_id) LIKE '%date%' -- I don't have any of datetimeoffset, smalldatetime nor time in the db. i have date, datetime and datetime2
order by [table], c.column_id;
```

**What I want:**
UTC values for all the data (actually are all GTM + 2). How to do that dinamically for all tables and columns instead of doing that manually?

Comment: This sounds like a terrible idea, if I am honest. Not to mention that now that you've `UPDATE`d `dbo.AtableOfMany` if you *do* `UPDATE` every single date and time value in your database then `dateStart` and `dateEnd` will be <Original Value> - 4 hours (not 2). Also how to you subtract 2 hours from a `date`? It has no time portion.

Comment: Using your sys.columns query, build the SQL statements dynamically which you can then execute using `exec()`

Comment: For your `datetimeoffset` values, I would suggest changing their values is plain wrong; surely they have the timezone that they are relevant for (CE(S)T?) so "subtracting" 2 hours from the value doesn't make it UTC. 2023-08-07 12:19:19 CEST "minus 2 hours" = 2023-08-07 10:19:19 CEST <> 2023-08-07 10:19:19 UTC.

Comment: For a UTC date, you need to subtract 1 day, not 2 hours.

Comment: The OP only has `date datetime datetime2` types according to the comments in the code sample, clearly `date` can't be used.

Comment: If they only have `datetime`/`datetime2` values, then I suppose the question then is how does the OP "know" all the values are UTC+2? Neither of the data types have a timezone property. Blanket `UPDATE`ing *every single value* could easily make the data as wrong (or more) as it currently is, with a bunch of values becoming "UTC -2" if any of their data is correctly "UTC".

Comment: Assuming GTM should actually be GMT and these are UK BST dates. I guess the OP needs to validate the data is within the UK BST range March-Oct dates, or perhaps he only has dates that exist within this range anyway, that detail is not provided.

Comment: Hi @Stu, I'll look into exec() function, although I've never used it.  Thank you for commenting on my request.

Comment: Hi @ThomA, thanks to take time for that.  I only have date type, datetime and datetime2 types in my database. For my understanding, which ok I can be wrong (be prepared for that), UTC are in fact GMT + 0, here in Italy GMT + 2 (the database actualy store dates as local time, i.e. GMT + 2). You should see the difference by calling 'SELECT GETDATE() AS LOCALTIME , GETUTCDATE() AS UTCTIME; ' I don't need tha format with CEST,z etc.. should be always be in the format of 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' with or without milliseconds. I'm clear now? Thanks

Comment: I know the difference between `GETDATE` and `GETUTCDATE()` @Mike97 .  This does mean that you are, currently, using CEST (Central European Summer Time), but Italy doesn't observe CEST all year, only for half of it; the other half it's CET (Central European Time) which is UTC+1. Blanket applying minus 2 hours will make a *significant* amount of your data be wrong *again*, as they will become UTC-1 values.

Comment: `EXEC` ([`EXECUTE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)) isn't a function, it's an operator.

Comment: What value would you expect for a value like 2022-10-30 01:30:00 to be changed to? Daylight saving ended at 2022-10-30 02:00:00+02:00, meaning that there were *two* 2022-10-30 01:30:00 events on that date (2022-10-30 01:30:00+02:00 and 2022-10-30 01:30:00+01:00); for such a value how do *you* know what timezone 2022-10-30 01:30:00 was in?

Comment: TL;DR of comments: If you don't know what timezone your times are appropriate for (and it appears you don't) any solution you apply will result in (some) wrong values.

Comment: From and to database will be done using c# converter which already takes care of the summer time changes, ad I hope to correctly assume that  if  in the database all values are UTC values, then I'll be fine. I'm wrong about that? About EXEC as already said I never used it, so thanks for the clarification. I'm listening to you carefully if you propose another strategy

Comment: Ok With your last post you make me thinking of THE problem.

Comment: I guess you can feel my pain now :-)

Comment: @ThomA using your suggested date (october) and then changing the month to november, the conversion looks ok with "SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST('2022-10-30 01:30:00' AS DATETIME) AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC');"  Isn't it?

Comment: I think you've missed my point. The `datetime`/`datetime2` value `2022-10-30T01:30:00` when generated by the functions `GETDATE()`/`SYSDATETIME()` could represent either `2022-10-30 01:30:00+01:00` or `2022-10-30 01:30:00+02:00`; the problem is you don't know which it's supposed to be because you have no offset data. `2022-11-30 01:30:00` will be `2022-11-30 01:30:00+01:00` because daylight saving doesn't end on that date. Much like `2023-08-07 13:34:45` will always be `2023-08-07 13:34:45+02:00`.